# Sharepoint Top and left side bar hide

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I Dont no how to hide or remove top bar and left side bar in sharepoint.

I am using Sharepoint designer and infopath.

Can you please help me

Comment: what are things you tried till now .. did you try to search in google at-least ...?

Answer (score 1):

To hide the top bar use this CSS (in your master page or in your specific page) :

```
#suiteBar {
  display: none !important;
  height: 30px;
}
```

If you want to hide 'ribbon' also then use following CSS:

```
#s4-ribbonrow {
  display: none !important;
  position: relative;
}
```

To hide side bar (left navigation):

```
#sideNavBox {
  display: none !important;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}
#contentBox {
  margin-left: 20px !important; /*moved content to left*/
  margin-right: 20px;
  min-width: 703px;
}
```